# Library compiling errors with alternate build of gcc

Tags: gcc, ld, hdf5

I have some fortran programs that would not compile in old versions of gfortran. I have to run multiple instances of this program and am using another system (a cluster system) which has centos5_x64 with gcc-4.1 !!

Therefore I had to build new version of gcc; I built both gcc-4.8.3 and gcc-4.9.2 in my home folder. These programs use hdf5 and so the latter also has to be compiled using the same compiler. I tested the fortran programs after removing the hdf5 dependency on both gfortran-4.8.3 and 4.8.9 and they get built and execute properly. I also tested simple C/C++ programs (with basic i/o and arithmetic) with the new gcc/g++(s); they work fine. Before compiling hdf5 libraries I set these environment variables:

```
PATH=<GCCPATH>:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<GCCLIB>
LD_RUN_PATH=<GCCLIB>
export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_RUN_PATH
```

**HDF5 specific instructions**

> 4.3.7. Specifying other libraries and headers
>           Configure searches the standard places (those places known by the
>           systems compiler) for include files and header files. However,
>           additional directories can be specified by using the CPPFLAGS
>           and/or LDFLAGS variables:
>
> ```
>         $ CPPFLAGS=-I/home/robb/include \
>           LDFLAGS=-L/home/robb/lib \
> ```

```
LDFLAGS=-L<GCCLIB>
CPPFLAGS=-I<GCCINCLUDE>
```

then configured as:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/HDF5 --enable-fortran
```

During make I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This happens with both versions of gcc but not with the versions installed in the standard location (This happened in another system too which had gcc 4.4 installed). With general searching I got to know that this error is associated with the absence of a `main()` and in such cases `-c` flag has to be passed. However all examples of this error were from people's personal scripts and were not for libraries. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Upgrading the system OS is not a choice as of now.

Comment: Have you tried building and executing simple program using gcc-4.8.3 and gcc-4.9.2 to make sure they are really working?

Comment: @doqtor Yes simple programs get built and executed properly. However I just tested gfortran. I don't have C/C++ scripts. Can make an example for each and try.

Comment: @doqtor simple C/C++ programs also work (just tested simple arithmetic operations and basic io)

Comment: The error you are getting looks very likely to be mixing old and new compiler stuff. I remember doing something similar long time ago and then I manually modified paths in hdf5 generated Makefile as opposed to redefining env variables. Alternatively you could install centos in virtual machine and overwrite the old gcc compiler.

Comment: @doqtor I thought of installing new OS in a virtual machine but then it has other problems. So did you modify Makefile.in ? And do you remember what all did you change. Is it possible for you to share the modified makefile?

Comment: I think I first ran configure and then I modified the resulted Makefile. It was few years ago, we don't use centos anymore, I tried to find some notes but to no avail, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the [comment by doqtor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466028/library-compiling-errors-with-alternate-build-of-gcc?noredirect=1#comment49034483_30466028), I modified the `Makefile` post configure. It seems that CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS were not set.

After setting the right CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS in the `Makefile`, the compilation happened successfully.